# Confused with the Isolated Storage with Multiple Assemblies Access

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage

I googled and searched a lot, but I got no luck.

I have a WindowsFormsApplication.exe and ConsoleApplication.exe.  I want both of them to access to the same IsolatedStorage, is it possible?

I tried using this in ConsoleApplication.exe:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetMachineStoreForApplication();
```

but I got:

```
IsolatedStorageException: Unable to determine application identity of the caller.
```

How can I fix this?
Or can I use this way?

P.S.: This is NOT a ClickOnce app.

Comment: It seems everyone is having fun on the Christmas night :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForSite()

More on that here.. http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Caching-of-in-and-around-your-Silverlight-application-part-2.aspx

Hope that helps :)
Pooran